# Do you need to supply all the info from the original JournalEntry when doing a JournalEntryMod?

Tags: quickbooks

The [docs](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) for IJournalEntryMod say that only the txnId, txnLineId, and the EditSequence are required for this call. I tried to change the account for one of the lines and I'm getting the error "Transaction not in balance".

1. Do you have to copy every value from the existing JournalEntry Line to the line appended to the JournalEntryModList?
2. Do you need to supply all the lines of the existing transaction? (I noticed this comment on the docs "note that in a mod request, inclding [sic] one line means that you must include all lines, modified or not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have to copy every value from the existing JournalEntry Line to the line appended to the JournalEntryModList?

You don't have to send every single element in the [JournalLineMod] again, but you DO have to send at least the [TxnLineID] for every line.

e.g. if you just send this:

```
<JournalEntryModRq>
<JournalEntryMod>
<TxnID>ABCD1234</TxnID>
<EditSequence>1234</EditSequence>
<TxnDate>some new date here</TxnDate>
</JournalEntryMod>
</JournalEntryModRq>
```

Then you're essentially telling QuickBooks to drop every single existing line item on that journal entry.

Instead, you have to *send the TxnLineID for every line item that you want to keep*. Any line item TxnLineID values that you do not send will be removed from the transaction.

So something like this:

```
<JournalEntryModRq>
<JournalEntryMod>
<TxnID>ABCD1234</TxnID>
<EditSequence>1234</EditSequence>
<TxnDate>some new date here</TxnDate>

<JournalLineMod>
<TxnLineID>An existing TxnLineID goes here</TxnLineID>
</JournalLineMod>
<JournalLineMod>
<TxnLineID>An existing TxnLineID goes here</TxnLineID>
</JournalLineMod>

<JournalLineMod>
 ... bla bla bla lots of new data goes here ...
</JournalLineMod>

</JournalEntryMod>
</JournalEntryModRq>
```